# SSRS report error in AX 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to create a basic SSRS report in Visual Studio 2010 with AX 2012.
I want to display basic CustTable data. When i link the dataset with the query CustTableSRS (a query in AOT), i get an error.
The error says,

> A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.

This doesnt happen if i do the same steps in AX 2009 with Visual Studio 2008.
On googling, i found that this has something to do with "misconfigured SPN".
SPN is Server Principal Name, a name given to a server instance in a Kerboros environment. But i am not able to set it right.
I am using AX2012 image running on Oracle VirtualBox.

Note: Sorry, not able to post screenshot since i am a newbie :)

Error log in Visual Studio

```
Error   3   The "GenerateRdlTask" task failed unexpectedly.
Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client.UserSessionServiceException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartReceiveBlob(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartReceiveBlob(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, ChannelBinding binding, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgrade(Stream stream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client.UserSessionService.IUserSessionService.GetUserSessionInfo(UserSessionServiceGetUserSessionInfoRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client.UserSessionClientInternal.<GetUserSessionInfo>b__0(IUserSessionService channel)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client.ServiceClientHelper.InvokeChannelOperation[TResult,TChannel](IServiceClient`1 client, Func`2 operationInvoker, Func`2 exceptionWrapper)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client.ServiceClientHelper.InvokeChannelOperation[TResult,TChannel](IServiceClient`1 client, Func`2 operationInvoker, Func`2 exceptionWrapper)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client.UserSessionClientInternal.GetUserSessionInfo()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client.UserSessionClient.GetUserSessionInfo()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Reports.Shared.UserInformationProxy.GetUserSessionInfo()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Reports.Shared.UserInformationProxy.GetUserLanguage()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Reports.Shared.ReportParameterPromptStringResolver.Resolve(Stream input, String language)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Deployment.Reports.GenerateRdlTask.GetRDLForDesign(IReportDesignDefinition reportDesign, String[] assemblyReferences)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Deployment.Reports.GenerateRdlTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\DynamicsTools\Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Design.Reporting.Modeling.targets   103 6   ReporDemoModel1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the same as Administrator, in order to see if same error arises. If Reporting is working properly, this is the first thing to try.

And for this type of developments, it's critical to have all CIL entirely compilated, and services (and service groups, there's one beginning by SRS and other by SAS) deployed. Check that the configuration client used by VS has properly configurated the services communications.